# Receiving error "failed precmd routine" when starting openfire on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, openfire

On a fresh install of OpenFire 3_8_2 on FreeBSD 8.0 that went flawless, when starting the service via "/usr/local/etc/rc.d/openfire start", the following error is generated:

WARNING: failed precmd routine for openfire

Would appreciate if anyone knows what is causing this problem and how I might resolve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this resulted in the "failed precmd" error, but I resolved it by setting openfire to run as a different user.

Thanks to anyone that looked at this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install the mysql-server package of your choice, and then just run:

`/usr/local/libexec/mysqld --initialize`

After that, just start your MySQL service; don't forget to add it to the rc.conf. Just runned into this to in a fresh install in FreeBSD 10.3.

Cheers.